# Removing two finger touch on Android Emulator

Tags: linux, flutter, android-emulator

I am running Linux Mint and are creating flutter apps. Once in a while when I change my workspace (CTRL + ALT + Left/Right) away from my android emulator then this weird tracer starts appearing and I can't get rid of it without closing everything on the emulator. The tracer follows my cursor and reacts to right click etc.

Has anyone any idea what this is?

#### Update

I just noticed that they are representing two fingers. How to get rid of it though?

[image: Android emulator]

Answer (score 10):

It's a bug I think. It should only appear when you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button and disappears as soon as you release the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button. To get rid of this press the zoom button once.
[image]

Comment: Does not help with zoom button click.